# thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2, address=0x38)

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am having this error on Xcode, any ideas please ?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: *(highScore) forKey: @"retry"];
```

I want to save `highScore` in the defaults database, `retry` is a button

Comment: You need to give some more details. How is `highScore` defined? Do you get an exception message?

Comment: highScore is property (nonatomic) NSInteger *highScore; in the .h file , and synthesize highScore; in the .m file. @Wain

Comment: More than likely, `highScore` is not a pointer to an integer, and thus the `*(highScore)` syntax is wrong. If `highScore` is just a simple integer, then you'd just do `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: highScore forKey: @"retry"];`. We need to see the declaration of `highScore` to advise you further.

Comment: If you have a new question, you'll have much better luck [posting it as its own entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than trying to edit a closed question that already has an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell they banned me from asking, because this one question got the -2 rating! and I really need an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for your integer to be stored as a pointer. Change your property to:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger highScore;
```

you also don't need to synthesise it, so remove that (the compiler does it for you, and it does a better job).

Then change your user defaults code to:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:highScore forKey:@"retry"];
[defaults synchronize];
```